# pandas: reduce memory usage df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df[[ 'year', 'month', 'day']])

Tags: python, pandas, memory, out-of-memory

I have a `df.shape` is `(130161370, 9)` .
It took  5xxxMB in memory .
When I run

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df[[ 'year', 'month', 'day']])
```

The memory usage flied to 30000MB until finished, then down to 6000MB . That is too huge ...

However, this is the only way I know to convert `[ 'year', 'month', 'day']` to `date` . Is there any way to reduce memory usage on converting ?

Comment: At this size, I would recommend just ditching pandas altogether and switching to something that can do distributed processing, efficiently, and performantly.

Comment: @coldspeed But the dataframe isn't so large, just 3GB after dump, and it could be done in single machine with a proper speed.Why do I spend more money and time switching to spark .

Comment: It's not about the memory. 130M rows is just beyond pandas capability. Take it from me, but you're free to choose your own path of destruction ;-)